# Why doesn't my coin disappear when my player collides with it?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

I just started coding so i still have so much to learn. Unity doesn't give any error when I play the game but also nothing happenes when the player touches the gold. I want the gold to dissapear when the playes touches it but I don't know why it doesn't work. (collision part is the last part)

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour
{

    private Rigidbody2D myRigidbody;
    private Animator anim;

    [SerializeField]
    private int speed;
    private bool lookright;


     void Start()
    {
        myRigidbody = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
        
        lookright = true;
    }

    
    void Update()
    {

        float horizontal = Input.GetAxis("Horizontal");
        movements(horizontal);
        changedirection(horizontal);

    }
    private void movements (float horizontal)
    {
        anim.SetFloat ("Walk", Mathf.Abs(horizontal));
        myRigidbody.velocity = new Vector2 (horizontal*speed, myRigidbody.velocity.y);

    }
    private void changedirection(float horizontal)
    {

        if (horizontal > 0 && !lookright || horizontal < 0 && lookright)
        {
            lookright = !lookright;
            Vector3 direction = transform.localScale;
            direction.x *= -1;
            transform.localScale = direction;
        }

    }

    void OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision2D other)
    {

        if (other.gameObject.tag == "gold")
        {
            other.gameObject.SetActive(false);
        }
        
    } }
```

[This is the Unity inspector of the gold](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmP4w.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`OnCollisionEnter2D(Collision collision)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnCollisionEnter2D.html) won't fire when you have its `IsTrigger` set to `true`. Change it to [`OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collider)`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MonoBehaviour.OnTriggerEnter2D.html) and it will work.

Take a look at the [documentation for colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).